# Kubernetes statefulset : other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Note: nfs server and permission are fine, I have checked PV and PVC is creating fine only statefulSet is giving me this error.

Error Message: The StatefulSet "auth-mongo-ss" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden
(err msg is straightforward but didn't help to solve it! what am I missing here ?)

Kubernetes(minkube) version:

Client Version: v1.20.2
Server Version: v1.20.2

OS:

Linux mint - 20

````
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: auth-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 250Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: manual
  nfs:
    path: /nfs/auth
    server: 192.168.10.104
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-serv
  labels:
    app: auth-mongo-serv
spec:
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-ss
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo-serv # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: auth-mongo-ss
  replicas: 1 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo-serv # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo-docker
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "250Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: auth-mongo-data
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: auth-mongo-data
      spec:
        storageClassName: manual
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 250Mi
    ```
````

Comment: you are probably trying to change a spec field on a existing statefulset other than `replicas`, `template`, and `updateStrategy` which is not allowed, you need to delete the existing statefulset and create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, Krishna, I have deleted the old one and again with a new one as well and still didn't work. Also, I took a sample of statefulset from official Kubernetes docs. Something very small i am missing (or doing wrong config which i am not able to catch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden` saying it all.

In `StatefultSet` only mutable (you can change/update) is `replicas`, `template`, and `updateStrategy`. Other than these fields in `Spec` you cannot change others fields during updates.

## Update

You have multiple issues:

1. in the `StatefuleSet` Spec you used `serviceName: auth-mongo-ss`, do you have this headless service?
2. In this service spec you did not give `selector`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-serv
  labels:
    app: auth-mongo-serv
spec:
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

An example of StatefulSet from k8s doc is given below, for statefulset you need one headless service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 3 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: Thanks, shahadat, then how would I add the mongo config to the spec if I am not allowed to change Spec? with volumenClaim. I am new to kubernetes so might be basic quetion i know :)

Comment: delete old one and create new one with your desired stuffs

Comment: please see the comments in the question, he has already tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Yup Kishna, will try again.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I first didnot notice comments, my bad! I Have updated my answer

Comment: @SahadatHossain, Thanks for point out the issue. My serviceName had a typo. Resolved. (I would give you an upvote but my reputation has not reached 125 yet! :))

Comment: @MeetPatel It's ok buddy! btw, you can accept the answer if it helps you, fyi

Comment: It's been a too long time that I have used StackOverflow. let me find it and do it.